# Extensive spacing

Tags: spacing

I get the extensive spacing when plotting the document: 
[image]

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section*{Sample Text}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item sample text.
 \item sample text.\par
 \begin{tikzpicture}[      
        every node/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt},
        x=1mm, y=1mm,
      ]   
     \node (fig1) at (0,0)
       {\includegraphics[scale=1,cfbox=gray]{CET850_DatSetContent.png}};
     \node (fig2) at (72,2)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{pointer_with_click.png}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \item sample text.
\end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce the problem without the two pictures `CET850_DatSetContent.png` and `pointer_with_click.png`.

Answer (score 3):

Option `twoside` enables the default `\flushbottom`. That means the contents of the page is stretched if necessary to align the bottom lines at the bottom of the pages.

The first image is quite large (I suspect even an overfull `\hbox` from the image snippet) and very likely does not fit on the first page; therefore, the image is forced to the next page leaving an underfull `\vbox` on the first page.

The image size can be set to the line width or less if necessary, e.g. something like:

```
\node[inner sep=0pt] (fig1) at (0, 0) {%
  \includegraphics[
    width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax,
    cfbox=gray,
  ]{CET850_DatSetContent.png}%
};
```